# Log in Button resized

Tags: login

At the website i'm currently running, the button for guests to log in is really tiny and essentially hard to find, i want to know if it's possible for me to resize the parameters, i'm currently using the free theme 'Hellowired' do i need to change the size through the correct form in the root directory? 
Or is this possible to work this out in Magento Backend itself?

Comment: can you explain in details or share screen shot?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Here are the details  http://i64.tinypic.com/htebzq.png

Comment: I think i found the correct source code, if anyone wanna help me out on how to change the sizes,  the website is itdd.nl/magento    in the style.css i found a few codes but i'm not sure which one i should change